# Spinner Control in Monodroid - Get ID and Text on Selection

Tags: xamarin.android, spinner

I have started exploring the Spinner control just now. I have pretty much achieved what I wanted but only the last step is missing. Here is what I have done so far.

I have a very simple class for this example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Merchant
{
    public Int64 MerchantId { get; set; }
    public String ShopName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ShopName;
    }
}
```

Here is the axml where I placed the Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="1280dip"
    android:layout_height="800dip">
    <TextView
        android:text="Select a merchant:"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblSelect"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:textSize="42dip" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinMerchant"
        android:layout_width="1000dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblSelect"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="20dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code is:

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Create your application here
        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MerchantSelect);

        List<Merchant> lstMerchant = new List<Merchant> ();
        lstMerchant.Add (new Merchant() { ShopName = "First Shop", MerchantId = 11 });
        lstMerchant.Add (new Merchant() { ShopName = "Second Shop", MerchantId = 12 });

        Spinner spinner = this.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinMerchant);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, lstMerchant);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> (spinner_ItemSelected);

        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        //Merchant merch = (Merchant)spinner.SelectedItem;
        string toast = string.Format ("Selected text is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText (this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
    }
```

I want to get the selected text as well as the ID behind it as soon as the selection is made. I get the text by `spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position)` but I can't seem to find anything that can give me the ID. If I try to do `Merchant merch = (Merchant)spinner.SelectedItem;` I get an exception: `Cannot convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'Merchant'`.

Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spinner only knows about the text because that's what you have in your `ToString()` method it. The adapter that's providing the spinner data has no idea it is dealing with `Merchant` objects.
To get to the actual Merchant object, youll have to make your `List<Merchant> lstMerchant` a member of your class.

Then change your selection handler:

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
       // Get the ID from your model.
        Merchant merch = this.lstMerchant[e.Position];
        var id = merch.MerchantId;
        string toast = string.Format ("Selected text is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText (this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Though I was hoping for a more - what should I say - 'framework supported' solution but this will work too.